# Não consigo fazer a verificação das caixas de texto

Tags: javascript

Gostaria de saber como eu faço pra calcular o IMC, mas antes disso verificar se a textfield foi preenchida.

E como formatar máscara da altura para autopreencher (X.XX)?

```html
<html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<head>
<center>
<title>testando JS</title>
<font face = "Corbel">
<body>
<br>
<img width= "200px" height="100px" align="center" src="imagem/IMC_full.png"/>
<br>
<br>
<form>
Digite seu peso (Kg)<br>
<input type="text" name="peso" id="peso" value="xx" maxlength="3" size="10" style="text-align:center"><br><br>
Digite sua altura (m)<br>
<input type="text" name="altura" id="altura" value="x.xx" maxlength="4" size="10" style="text-align:center"><br><br>

<input type="submit" value="Calcular IMC" onclick="calculaIMC(),teste()">
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<img width="800px" height="250px" align="center" src="imagem/tabela-imc.jpg" />
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
function calculaIMC(){
var peso = document.getElementById("peso").value;
var altura = document.getElementById("altura").value;
var imc = Math.round(peso /(altura*altura));
alert("Seu IMC é "+imc);
}

function teste(){
if (peso ==""){
    alert("Prencha peso");
    document.peso.focus();
    return false;
}
if (altura ==""){
    alert("Preencha altura");
    document.altura.focus();
    return false;
}
}
</script>
</center>
</head>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

## Calculando o IMC

Tente chamar apenas o método `calculaIMC()` no momento do clique do `submit` e dentro dele coloque as validações antes de calcular o IMC.

## Validando se o campo foi preenchido

Da forma como você está fazendo resolve, você só tem que passar o conteúdo de dentro do método `teste()` para o `calculaIMC()`, deixando mais ou menos assim o seu método de calcular o IMC:

```
function calculaIMC(){

var peso = document.getElementById("peso").value;
var altura = document.getElementById("altura").value;

if (peso ==""){
    alert("Prencha peso");
    document.peso.focus();
    return;
}
if (altura ==""){
    alert("Preencha altura");
    document.altura.focus();
    return;
}

var imc = Math.round(peso /(altura*altura));
alert("Seu IMC é "+imc);
}
```

## Aplicando máscara

Acho que ao invés de utilizar máscaras você poderia usar um próprio recurso para o tipo de dado que você está entrando nos seus Input's, por exemplo, substituir a seguinte input:

```
<input type="text" name="peso" id="peso" value="xx" maxlength="3" size="10" style="text-align:center">
```

Por um input do tipo `number` pode fazer com que você não necessite de uma máscara de números, e também faz muito mais sentido, por ser um campo onde só pode entrar um número, ficando da seguinte forma:

```
<input type="number" name="peso" id="peso" value="xx" maxlength="3" size="10" style="text-align:center">
```

A mesma alteração se aplica ao input da altura, mas ao invés de `number` utilize `decimal`.

Comment: Valeu mesmo pela resposta amigo!

Answer (score 1):

Primeiro, a sua HTML está mal-formada. O `<meta charset="utf-8">` deveria ficar dentro do `<head>`. O `<center>` e o `<font face = "Corbel">` deveriam ficar dentro do `<body>`. O `<body>` não deve ficar dentro do `<head>`. A ordem é assim:

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Testando JS</title>
        <!-- Outras tags aqui se você quiser. -->
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- O conteúdo da página vem aqui. -->
    </body>
</html>
```

Segundo, as tags `<center>` e `<font>` são consideradas obsoletas há 20 anos! Desde 1997, quando saiu o HTML 4. Elas não devem mais ser utilizadas. O HTML 5 não as aceita mais (embora o navegador pode ainda aceitar por questãao de compatibilidade). Use CSS no lugar delas.

Terceiro, na sua função `teste`, o `document.peso` e `document.altura` não existem. Use o `document.getElementById("peso")` que você está usando na outra função.

Quarto, dentro da função `teste`, as variáveis `peso` e `altura` não estão definidas. O fato de elas estarem definidas dentro de `calculaIMC` faz com que elas só existam dentro de `calculaIMC`.

Quinto, não use duas funções dentro do `onclick`.

Sexto, usar `<input type="button">` custuma ser bem mais fácil de trabalhar que `<inpu type="submit">`. Você pode dar o `submit` via javascript.

Aqui vai o seu código revisado, clique no botão azul <kbd>Executar</kbd> lá em baixo para testar.

```js
function calculaIMC(peso, altura) {
    return Math.round(peso / (altura * altura));
}

function teste() {
    var elementoResultado = document.getElementById("resultado");
    var elementoPeso = document.getElementById("peso");
    var elementoAltura = document.getElementById("altura");
    var peso = parseFloat(elementoPeso.value);
    var altura = parseFloat(elementoAltura.value);
    if (isNaN(peso) || peso <= 0.0) {
        elementoResultado.innerHTML = "Preencha o valor do peso com um número.";
        elementoPeso.focus();
        return;
    }
    if (isNaN(altura) || altura <= 0.0) {
        elementoResultado.innerHTML = "Preencha o valor da altura com um número.";
        elementoAltura.focus();
        return;
    }
    var imc = calculaIMC(peso, altura);
    elementoResultado.innerHTML = "Seu IMC é " + imc + ".";

    //document.getElementById("formulario").submit();
}
```

```html
<form id="formulario">
    <div>
        Digite seu peso (Kg):
        <input type="text" name="peso" id="peso" value="xx" maxlength="3" size="10" style="text-align: center">
    </div>

    <div>
        Digite sua altura (m):
        <input type="text" name="altura" id="altura" value="x.xx" maxlength="4" size="10" style="text-align: center">
    </div>

    <div id="resultado"></div>

    <input type="button" value="Calcular IMC" onclick="javascript:teste()">
</form>
```

Ah, vê no código esse `//document.getElementById("formulario").submit();`? Então, se você tirar o `//` ele vai fazer o submit do formulário, mas só se o peso e a altura forem válidas.